# Phones with external keyboard. Prevent change orientation

Tags: android, keyboard, orientation

I have a big issue for those phones that have not only the softkeyboard that all phones have (on screen)... i'm talking about those phones with external keyboard hardware.

in these moment I've set all activities, forcing one way, **portrait**. Now here comes the problem when the user flips his external keyboard, the activity changes orientation forcing the app to close.

if someone dosn't know which phones i'm talking about here is an example:
[Phone with external keyboard](http://cdn.skattertech.com/files/2009/11/htc-touch-pro2-keyboard.jpg)

Piece of my manifest;

```
<activity
      android:name=".Splash"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:noHistory="true"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
     android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
     android:name=".MainActivity"
     android:screenOrientation="portrait"
     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
</activity>
```

How can make the keyboard to ignore orientation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your activity manifest.

```
android:configChanges= "keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Comment: in every activity, or just on the first one?

Comment: In any activity that you don't want android to do the default reset when the keyboard is pulled out.